# initializing dateTimepicker wont get the value of input field

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Using http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ If i do `paastetoodeAlgusAeg.datepicker('getDate')` Then i get the correct date but time is always 00.00.00. How can i fix this ?

```
<div class="vkTimePickerInputKontainer">
                    <input id="paastetoodeAlgus"
                           name="paastetoodeAlgus"
                           class="vkTimePicker"
                           value="${g.formatDate(format: grailsApplication.config.grails.app.dateTimeFormat, date: valjakutseInstance?.paastetoodeAlgus)}"
                    />
                </div>

jQuery('.vkTimePicker').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
            showSecond:true,
            validateBeforeClose: VKREG.validateDateTimeChronology
        });
```

Edit1:

Solved it. Problem arise from the fact that somone had made a typo in the format type. it was difficult to fix because the code is very very spread out.

Comment: please provide the Js and css CDN link for check this issue.

Comment: CDN link? What is that?

Comment: Can you please provide Jsfiddle?